# SQL Server and XML Utilization

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to utilize XML with SQL Server.  All I'm trying to do is print out all three guests.  When I run my code, it only shows the prints the first guest's information, and I need all three guest's information to be printed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT Guest.GuestID, GuestFirst, GuestLast, CheckinDate, Nights
FROM GUEST
JOIN FOLIO
ON Guest.GuestID = Folio.GuestID
FOR XML RAW

Declare @idoc int
Declare @xmldoc nvarchar(4000)


Set @xmldoc = '
<ROOT>
<GUEST>
<GuestID>4431</GuestID>
<GuestFirst>Lacey</GuestFirst>
<GuestLast>Byington</GuestLast>
<RESERVATIONDETAIL>
<CheckInDate>2016-08-02</CheckInDate>
<Nights>2</Nights>
</RESERVATIONDETAIL>
</GUEST>

<GUEST>
<GuestID>5563</GuestID>
<GuestFirst>Jonathan</GuestFirst>
<GuestLast>Langford</GuestLast>
<RESERVATIONDETAIL>
<CheckInDate>2016-08-05</CheckInDate>
<Nights>2</Nights>
</RESERVATIONDETAIL>
</GUEST>

<GUEST>
<GuestID>6680</GuestID>
<GuestFirst>Tanner</GuestFirst>
<GuestLast>Olson</GuestLast>
<RESERVATIONDETAIL>
<CheckInDate>2015-09-11</CheckInDate>
<Nights>3</Nights>
</RESERVATIONDETAIL>
</GUEST>
</ROOT>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmldoc

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT', 3)
WITH
(
    GuestID smallint 'GUEST/GuestID',
    GuestFirst varchar(30) 'GUEST/GuestFirst',
    GuestLast varchar(30) 'GUEST/GuestLast',
    CheckinDate smalldatetime 'GUEST/RESERVATIONDETAIL/CheckInDate',
    Nights tinyint 'GUEST/RESERVATIONDETAIL/Nights'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead xml document try it with xquery,

```
DECLARE @xmldoc XML

Set @xmldoc = '
<ROOT>
  <GUEST>
    <GuestID>4431</GuestID>
    <GuestFirst>Lacey</GuestFirst>
    <GuestLast>Byington</GuestLast>
    <RESERVATIONDETAIL>
      <CheckInDate>2016-08-02</CheckInDate>
      <Nights>2</Nights>
    </RESERVATIONDETAIL>
  </GUEST>
  <GUEST>
    <GuestID>5563</GuestID>
    <GuestFirst>Jonathan</GuestFirst>
    <GuestLast>Langford</GuestLast>
    <RESERVATIONDETAIL>
      <CheckInDate>2016-08-05</CheckInDate>
      <Nights>2</Nights>
    </RESERVATIONDETAIL>
  </GUEST>
  <GUEST>
    <GuestID>6680</GuestID>
    <GuestFirst>Tanner</GuestFirst>
    <GuestLast>Olson</GuestLast>
    <RESERVATIONDETAIL>
      <CheckInDate>2015-09-11</CheckInDate>
      <Nights>3</Nights>
    </RESERVATIONDETAIL>
  </GUEST>
</ROOT>'

SELECT
    a.b.value('GuestID[1]','smallint') AS GuestID,
    a.b.value('GuestFirst[1]','varchar(30)') AS GuestFirst,
    a.b.value('GuestLast[1]','varchar(30)') AS GuestLast,
    a.b.value('RESERVATIONDETAIL[1]/CheckInDate[1]','smalldatetime') AS CheckInDate,
    a.b.value('RESERVATIONDETAIL[1]/Nights[1]','tinyint') AS Nights
FROM @xmldoc.nodes('ROOT/GUEST') AS a(b)

GO
```

btw, the select query you have given on the top will not produce the same xml which you have given below.

Answer (score 0):

@Jatin answer is good, you can use xquery. You can also use OPENXML like this:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmldoc

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/GUEST', 3)
WITH
(
    GuestID smallint './GuestID',
    GuestFirst varchar(30) './GuestFirst',
    GuestLast varchar(30) './GuestLast',
    CheckinDate smalldatetime './RESERVATIONDETAIL/CheckInDate',
    Nights tinyint './RESERVATIONDETAIL/Nights'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  You just need to make this small change:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/*', 3)
WITH
(
GuestID smallint 'GuestID',
GuestFirst varchar(30) 'GuestFirst',
GuestLast varchar(30) 'GuestLast',
CheckinDate smalldatetime 'RESERVATIONDETAIL/CheckInDate',
Nights tinyint 'RESERVATIONDETAIL/Nights'
)
```